# Why doesn't my input from subprocessing module go through netcat spawned /bin/bash after I make it a bit stable with pty?

Tags: python, php, linux, subprocess, netcat

Consider this python script:

```
import subprocess

nc = subprocess.Popen(["/bin/bash"], stdin=subprocess.PIPE, text=True)
nc.stdin.write("nc localhost 2222\n")
nc.stdin.write("pwd\n")
```

When I listen with netcat as `nc -lnvp 2222`
I successfully connect and send the string `pwd` nothing more happens of course.

Now I get a non stable php reverse shell(Completely new event) and I connect through netcat successfully. I execute this script to upgrade shell and print current directory. By the way that listener is another `Popen` instance.

```
import subprocess

nc = subprocess.Popen(["/bin/bash"], stdin=subprocess.PIPE, text=True)
nc.stdin.write("nc localhost 2222\n")
nc.stdin.write('python3 -c "import pty;pty.spawn(\'/bin/bash\')"\n')
nc.stdin.write('pwd\n')
```

Now when I execute that python script, I expected the input will go through netcat, get executed in that new bash tty and spawn a stable shell and pass `pwd` to return current directory. But this script only works upto spawing stable shell and then **stdin** input doesn't go  through `nc` or something else happens that I'm not aware of.
What's happening here?

Edit: I need to be able to run multiple commands. Using `subprocess.communicate(input=<command>)` causes deadlock and can't accept stdin.

Comment: I would advise using the `process.communicate()` rather than writing in the `stdin` using `.write`, [here's](https://docs.python.org/3/library/subprocess.html#subprocess.Popen.communicate) a reference as to why.

Comment: The docs clearly state that:
```txt
Use communicate() rather than .stdin.write, .stdout.read or .stderr.read to avoid deadlocks due to any of the other OS pipe buffers filling up and blocking the child process. 
```

Comment: Sorry, I forgot to state I need a persistent process where I can input more than one command. Apparently, the `subprocess.communicate()` terminates the process with something called deadlock.